# Is Fitnesse only used as a acceptance test tool based on integration testing?

Tags: selenium, fitnesse, integration-testing, system-testing

I have read a lot about Fitnesse over the last week. From what I have heard, Fitnesse is commonly used as an acceptance testing tool that relies on a set of integration tests, as mentioned at [Agile Testing: A Practical Guide for Testers and Agile Teams](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001QL5N4K) and some other books and pages.

I am serching for a tool that allows business people to create their own set of acceptance tests that will or will not be automated by our QA Team. The big issue here is that we do not have all the means to do integration testing right now, as we are lacking people and resources to do so. Bu we do have a QA team that does automated system testing using selenium.

So my question is: is it possible do combine Fitnesse and Selenium to test a web application the same way we do with our automated system testing (I mean, by using the user interface to execute the test)?

I know that there are plugins and stuff that allows both Fitnesse and Selenium to work togheter, but I want to know if this is a valid approach and if it is usual at the QA world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you want to have a tool which can translate requirements/test cases (written by business people with no experience in programming) into executable code.

In our practice FitNesse is not that tool. We started with FitNesse, and keep maintaining existing tests and even adding new when feasible, but these tests are written by developers, not business people. For them, we use formalized process (series of meetings and rules, not a software product) which requires business people to write documents with requirements and test cases (described in business terms), and developers/QA translate these into scripts for manual testing, or automated test, or unit tests, as appropriate. Important part is to communicate to disclose any misunderstanding and omissions, not to automagically translate document written in business language into code.

FitNesse language, even if user-oriented, is way too quirky and confusing for people without programming experience. And it is more hassle to write test in it than using plain old Python and Selenium.

EDIT:
Selenium gives you "open browser, click on stuff, check stuff" capability. FitNesse is another way to do it (and present results in Fit), using HTML generated from Selenium IDE. What you are looking for is (I think) test runner, like Jenkins, to run test written in Selenium.

I think that there is confusion what Selenium is, caused by complete redesign of what Selenium is :-) (I know I was confused). Very roughly:

- Selenium 1 was IDE (capable of generating HTML which FitNesse could execute) + javascript injected to tested HTML pages to interact with pages ("click, check").
- Selenium 2 does "click, check" by using each browser native automation capabilities (when browser responds to specially crafted URLs). Se2 does not inject any JS.

Selenese code generated by IDE (Se1) was pretty weak (no parameters, no loops - just exact replay of previous actions), so i.e. you cannot enter current date or date 2 days from now if page did not have a widget to do that. Se2 code is standard language (Python, Java, ++) you already know and love, easier to scale.

So I do not see any reason to consider FitNesse. [Fit is considered dead by own authors](http://ericlefevre.net/wordpress/2009/03/06/is-fit-dead-a-debate-on-twitter/) and [important part is the communication, not tools](http://gojko.net/2010/03/01/are-tools-necessary-for-acceptance-testing-or-are-they-just-evil/) but of course it is your system and your project.

Comment: Well, I am not looking for a too which can translate requirements into code. I want to know if Fitnesse can be automated using selenium. By using selenium I mean opening a browser, clicking on stuff, checking stuff, etc. I have people that can automated the Fitnesse tests and they are programmers.

Comment: I agree when you say that meetings can be the way to go. Meeting with business people to translate what they want to be tested in a test case seems to me a good idea, that is why I am giving you +1

Comment: I added an edit because it grew longer that could fit in comments.